# Как в C++ Builder можно задать массив объектов типа TImage?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

Вот код:

```
TImage *masImage;
*masImage TImage[15];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятный вопрос...
Как определить массив объектов типа `Type`?

```
Type array[N];
```

Ну, или

```
Type * array = new Type[N];
...
delete[] array;
```

Вас это интересовало?

Comment: Да, большое спасибо